# Mongoose find model method generates wrong query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I am trying to do a simple find({}) in my DB using Mongoose in a NestJS project.

My code is like this:

```
constructor(@InjectModel('MyModel') private readonly myModel: Model<MyModel>) {}
findAll(){
   ...

   let result: any = await this.myModel
     .find()
     .limit(5)
     .exec();

   ...

}
```

With the Mongoose debug activated I can see the generated query in my console:

```
ofertas.find({}, { limit: 5, projection: {} })
```

When I go to the DB and use this query it returns the following error:

> "An empty sub-projection is not a valid value. Found empty object at path"

This projection:{} key-pair is generated every time automatically.

My question is: how can I get Mongoose to generate the following query?

```
find({}).limit(5)
```

Comment: Which version of Mongoose and MongoDB are you using?

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar Mongo v4.4.4, Mongoose v5.12.1 and @nestjs/mongoose v7.2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the following worked after a reload of my api.

```
let result: any = await this.myModel
      .find(conditions)
      .skip(0),
      .limit(5);
```

It is strange because it generates the same Mongo query that does not work inside the database.

```
mymodel.find({}, { skip:0, limit: 5, projection: {} })
```

But it works fine with my API, so I am going to register this here.